# Appending JSON data to ListView

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to append following JSON data:

```
[
  {
    "idfruits": "1",
    "fruit": "Apple"
  },
  {
    "idfruits": "2",
    "fruit": "Orange"
  },
  {
    "idfruits": "3",
    "fruit": "Banana"
  },
  {
    "idfruits": "4",
    "fruit": "Raspberry"
  },
  {
    "idfruits": "5",
    "fruit": "Coconut"
  }
]
```

With following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "index.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataype: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                var items = [];
                $.each(data, function (key, fruit_info) {
                    items.push('<li id="fruit_' + fruit_info.idfruits + '">' + fruit_info.fruit + '</li>');
                });

                $(items.join('')).appendTo('#listy');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Unfortunately the code gives following error:

```
TypeError: invalid 'in' operand obj
typeof length === "number" && length > 0 && ( length - 1 ) in obj );
```

My goal was to make a *generic* method that always parses first JSON value as `key` and second as `val`.
Is this possible?

Comment: What does your returned JSON look like, you can use fiddler to easily see it.  I see that you put some, but is it actually what was returned?

Comment: `<script>` needs a language. `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: @JoeFrambach, i have corrected this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. ECMAScript specifies hash behavior as such: http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-8.6

> An Object is an **unordered collection** of properties. Each property consists of a name, a value and a set of attributes.

You cannot assume that given a hash like `{"idfruits":"1","fruit":"Apple"}`, the id will be first and the fruit will be second. You will need to call them by name.

Very good question, by the way.

To do what you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "index.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataype: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            var items = [];
            $.each(data, function (key, fruit_info) {
                items.push('<li id="fruit_' + fruit_info.idfruits + '">' + fruit_info.fruit + '</li>');
            });

            $(items.join('')).appendTo('#listy');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I see. but how do i access the data?

Comment: @JavaCake the term "key" is kind of misleading.  That is actually the index of the current element in the array that is being processes.

Comment: @Justin +1. If the variable won't be used for anything, I like to just call it `i`.

Comment: You also need to define `items`. I've updated with where that should go.

Comment: Also, `1`, `2`, `3`, etc are **terrible** `id`s for elements.

Comment: @JoeFrambach, i know, but these are directly from my SQL table.

Comment: @JoeFrambach, the JSON data i pasted is by doing `console.log(data)`.

Comment: Actually, those IDs are invalid. "ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")."

Comment: Just change it to `'<li id="fruit_' + fruit_info.idfruits` or whatever.

Comment: @JoeFrambach, i have followed all corrections, but still same error occurs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27881/discussion-between-javacake-and-joe-frambach)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want use `fruit` instead of `value`

Try this

```
 $.each(data, function(key, val) {
        items.push('<li id="' + this.fruit+ '">' + this.fruit + '</li>');
  });
```

Comment: So i cant avoid using the actual names? Is there no chance that i can make it generic so that first value always is `key` and second begin `val` in `{"idfruits":"1","fruit":"Apple"}`.

Comment: You can do by passing keyName in JSON object and use this[keyName].