# How to append items to a listview through JSON data and refresh it?

Tags: jquery, listview, each, appendto, appframework

I am using intel's app framework. I got the following snippet from another answer(on jquery mobile) in stack overflow. But it is for jquery mobile and it had a function to refresh the listview after appending.

As I am in the learning stage, I couldn't figure out how to append the JSON data to a list view and refresh it. It will be a great help if someone could help me with this.

On running this code, I am getting the following error in my console. Also I would like to know if there is an alternative to Jquery Mobile's .listview('refresh') function.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: items is not defined

```
 $.each(data.mycontent, function(key, val) {
         items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
               });

          $('<ul/>', {                           
              html: items.join('')
             }).appendTo('#mylist');
```

My JSON data is in the following format

```
{"mycontent":{"content_id":"5","body":"foo content","heading":"My list heading"}
```

Comment: Probably try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15887424/1500341

Comment: Thanks. This answer helped me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614970/how-to-create-list-from-json-array

Comment: I have not been able to resolve the issue of refreshing content which has been added dynamically or appended in Intel App Framework, to effectively apply required CSS styles. This is possible in jQuery Mobile through .trigger() and .create() but where is this in Intel App Framework? I am currently resorting to attributing styles inline in order to apply CSS. Any advice would be appreaciated. Thanks